# Calling a server side method in client side in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the JavaScript that I have to use in my ASP.NET page, how to change it so that it works in ASP.NET?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            /**
            * These are not angles - these are values. The appropriate angles are calculated
            */

            <% Message message = (Message)request.getSession().getAttribute("message");

            out.print("var pie1 = new RGraph.Pie('pie1',"+Statistics.messagePercentStats(message.getMessageID()) + ")"); %>

             // Create the pie object
            pie1.Set('chart.key', ['Read', 'Received', 'Not Received']);
            pie1.Set('chart.colors',['#86cf21', '#eaa600', '#e01600']);
            pie1.Set('chart.title', "Message Status");
            pie1.Set('chart.align', 'left');
            pie1.Set('chart.shadow', true);
            pie1.Set('chart.radius', 80);
            pie1.Set('chart.labels.sticks', false);
            pie1.Set('chart.highlight.style', '2d'); // Defaults to 3d anyway; can be 2d or 3d


            if (!RGraph.isIE8()) 
            {
                pie1.Set('chart.zoom.hdir', 'center');
                pie1.Set('chart.zoom.vdir', 'up');
                pie1.Set('chart.labels.sticks', false);
                pie1.Set('chart.labels.sticks.color', '#aaa');
            }
            pie1.Draw();
        }
    </script>
```

How should I change this line to get value from my class which is named `messagePercentStats`?

```
RGraph.Pie('pie1',"+Statistics.messagePercentStats(message.getMessageID()) + ")"); %>
```

Comment: you will have to implement some kind of Webservice to do this - you cannot use a object *living* on your server just from the browser - there are some frameworks tools that make those magic happen (WebSharper and F# comes to mind) but I don't think there is anything like this for *plain* ASP.NET in C#

Comment: "after page load"? Page load will be executed on your server and is just a step to render HTML that gets send to the browser. When the browser finaly executes the JavaScript above a object you created in PageLoad might even have been reclaimed by the GC - no as I said you have to create a WebService (or similiar) and call this in your JavaScript code.

Comment: This looks like Java in there. In such case you'll have to translate the Java code to C#

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be trying to do this, assuming `RGraph.Pie` is client-side.

```
RGraph.Pie('pie1',
           '<%= Statistics.messagePercentStats(
                     ((Message)request.Session["message"]).getMessageID() %>');
```